# Multiple Magento installs on seperate servers. One Inventory.

Tags: inventory, multiple

I am curious if this is possible:

I have several Magento websites with the same products all on their own servers. So each store is its' own brand but sells the same products. These are all completely seperate instances of Magento. These sites are not all connected with multistore nor do I want them to be for my own personal reasons.

Say we have store 1, store 2 and store 3. They all have roughly (if not) the same exact products, with different urls etc. Here is how I would like this process to work:

Somebody purchases a product from store 2.
Store 1, 2 and 3 ALL have that same product pulled out of inventory.

Same goes for the other stores. If someone buys a product from store 1, then store 1, 2 and 3, would all have one taken from their inventory. Basically I want each site to have the same exact inventory. I understand that this is exactly what multistore could do for me, but I am not willing to go that route.

Im assuming this may have to be done through a third party so if I was on the third party website, any updates to stock would take place on all 3 sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A neat solution is to use an Inventory Management system that will act as a server, keeping your stock in sync across the different Magento installations.

[Megaventory](http://www.megaventory.com) is a [Magento compatible ERP](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/inventory-management-for-multiple-locations.html) which adds inventory management in multiple locations, ordering and reporting capabilities to your ecommerce store. It also features a powerful manufacturing module that ties well with Magento's bundle products.

If you use this solution, you will be handling all your ordering and your warehouse through Megaventory which will serve all the product details and the stock levels to your different e-commerce sites.

Also, since we plan to add integrations with more ecommerce platforms and other services so you can start building a powerful modular system to automate your business operations and data analysis.

Comment: So this extension is capable of doing what I described above? I understand from what I have read that you can keep track of all the inventory levels off of one main interface, however I am wondering if it will automatically allow Magento to pull 1 product out of inventory for each store per 1 product purchased regardless of which store it was purchased from.

Comment: It works exactly like this. If an order in one store affects the stock, the stock quantities will automatically be updated in all the other shops that are connected with Megaventory.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done theoretically with one observer per store and 2 curl calls to decrease stocks in the other 2 stores.

My idea is something like this:

1. You purchase Product1 in Store1.
2. sales_order_place_after event fires 2 curl calls to Store2 and Store3 with Product1 sku or product id.
3. In Store2 and Store3 you decrease the qty for the Product1 with some code.
4. Done.

This might be complex to configure since every store should point to the other 2, but that might be doable with 2 system config. Also sku/product id should be the same in all the stores. Or atleast have one attribute used as an ID to match products between stores.

Comment: can it be done by all of stores pointing to the same DB?

Comment: OP mentioned you did not wanted to use a multistore. But yes, man can use the same DB and configure the base_url in the app/etc/local.xml file among other store configs.

Comment: I didn't ask the initial question :-). thanks for explanation

Comment: My bad, sorry about that.

Comment: I can also see how this theoretically can be done however I really am looking for a straightforward answer on how EXACTLY to do it, or if there is an extension that can do exactly this. (Haven't read the below comment yet)

Comment: I'm not sure if there is an extension for this. Keep in mind that this is a community forum and not a do-this-for-me forum. Besides that, this is not the most complex extension in the world, you might want to code it yourself in a couple of hours.